# Not getting timezone from co-ordinates

Tags: typescript, azure, maps, azure-maps

I am using a GET url of azure map services to get the time zone from latitude and longitude. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/timezone/gettimezonebycoordinates

When I try it with postman, I get the correct timezone, but when I do the same thing from my code, I am not getting proper response.

```
let url =
      "https://atlas.microsoft.com/timezone/byCoordinates/json?subscription-key=" +
      subsciptionKey +
      "&api-version=1.0&query=" +
      latitude +
      "," +
      longitude;
    var settings = {
      async: true,
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      header: {
        // "x-ms-client-id": "3f13b1ef-547e-4594-b5db-7a70a68d3799",
        "Accept-Language": "EN"
      }
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
```

Below is the result I get from postman,

```
{
    "Version": "2019a",
    "ReferenceUtcTimestamp": "2019-04-02T13:51:58.6714007Z",
    "TimeZones": [
        {
            "Id": "Asia/Kolkata",
            "Names": {
                "ISO6391LanguageCode": "EN",
                "Generic": "India Standard Time",
                "Standard": "India Standard Time",
                "Daylight": "India Standard Time"
            },
            "ReferenceTime": {
                "Tag": "IST",
                "StandardOffset": "05:30:00",
                "DaylightSavings": "00:00:00",
                "WallTime": "2019-04-02T19:21:58.6714007+05:30",
                "PosixTzValidYear": 2019,
                "PosixTz": "IST-5:30"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But in case of my code, "Generic" field is empty. It says "No supported language code supplied".

Id: "Asia/Kolkata"
Names:
Daylight: ""
Generic: ""
ISO6391LanguageCode: "No supported language code supplied"
Standard: ""

Comment: Can you provide the coordinates you are using so we can try and reproduce this issue. Can you check the network traffic in your app to ensure the request is successful. Take a look at the query parameters being sent to the service from your app as possible something might be getting added.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message describes, this is caused when the service can't determine language/localization support for a time zone.

In your scenario, the problem appears to be that you are trying to add a header to the AJAX request via jQuery's `ajax` function, but note that their property to specify headers is `headers`, not `header` as you used. So your settings need to be changed to:

```
var settings = {
  async: true,
  url: url,
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept-Language": "EN"
  }
};
```

I actually ran into the `No supported language code supplied` error as well but for a different reason. If I used Postman to access a URL like:

https://atlas.microsoft.com/timezone/byCoordinates/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key=[your-key-here]&query=36.6209994,-92.1343022

and set the `Accept-Language` header to a location code they don't support, it will return the `ISO6391LanguageCode: "No supported language code supplied"` error.

I was setting the `Accept-Language` header to a location code listed on their [Localization support in Azure Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/supported-languages) page, like `en-US` in my case, and strangely, I would get that error message.

If I changed the location code to just `en` instead, it works.

You can get back valid time zone names by either:

1. Leaving off the header entirely (which will [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/timezone/gettimezonebycoordinates#request-headers) the language returned to English or "en").
2. Using just the first part of the language code (i.e. use `en` instead of `en-US`).